# How do I disable globally directory listing in Apache?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, apache-2.4

I have alias for app.example.com/Upload and virtual host app.example.com and main web site x.x.x.x and subdomain23.example.com and someotherhost.com etc etc...

I want to disable directory browsing/listing for every domain alias etc . How do I do this with single edit?

Answer (score 2):

You can turn off the `mod_autoindex` module that generates this listings, but this will result in a 404 if there is no index file present in a directory and you request that directory.